# What is the install4j default installation directory

Tags: install4j

Can someone confirm about the default installation directory for the **install4j**.
It seems like its **Program file** in windows as `context.getVariable("sys.installationDir").toString()` always returns `Program File/myInstallerName`. So just wanted to know where it is being set in the installer wizard and from where it is getting `myInstallerName`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default installation directory is defined on the "Installer options" step of the media wizard. By default, it is set to `${compiler:sys.shortName}`.

Comment: Thanks Ingo for reply.